# Front-running issue in Staking

Tags: solidity, erc-20, frontrunning

so I got a code which I suspect is prone to frontrunning at least theoretically.

```
function deposit(uint _amount) public {
        uint256 _pool = balance();
        uint256 _before = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        uint256 _after = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        _amount = _after.sub(_before); // Additional check for deflationary tokens
        uint256 shares = 0;
        if (totalSupply() == 0) {
            shares = _amount;
        } else {
            shares = (_amount.mul(totalSupply())).div(_pool);
        }
        _mint(msg.sender, shares);

        earn();
    }
```

Here is a test case which I'm considering:

Consider there are two users, User A and B
User A called deposit() with amount as 100, at that time, the contract balance was let's say 100. Now, variable _before
will be initialised with 100. But the transaction for the transfer of token from user A to contract address is still pending. Meanwhile
User B called deposit() with amount as 400, as contract balance is still not updated. The contract balance is still 100 and so as _before variable for B will also be 100, user B deposits 400, a new balance that is _after variable will be
400 + 100 that is 500. Now the _amount variable will be  _after - _before that 500 -100 that is 400.

Now, the pending transaction of User A is succeeded, it deposits its 100 amount. But now the _after variable calculated will be the new balance(as user B has already deposited prior to A's pending transaction, for eg, by giving a higher gas price)
Now, _amount calculated for A will be _after - before that is 600 - 100 that is 500. and now User A’s shares will be affected even though User A has deposited his 100 tokens legitimately

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 1):

No, what you are describing is not possible with that function.

Transactions are always executed entirely before another transaction starts to be executed (transactions are executed synchronously). That means that the `deposit()` function would need to be done up to the end, including the transfer of tokens, before another `deposit()` transaction would be initiated.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Undead8. Can you help with some supporting references to learn about transaction executions?